# Open an existing spreadsheet in write_only mode

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am suffering from memory consumption issues when streaming data into an existing Excel template using OpenPyXl.

My process is as follows:

1. Open existing template
2. Stream data into 3 different sheets
3. Save the workbook and download to the user

Code below:

```
path = r'template.xlsx'

output = BytesIO()
# Saving to Excel
book = load_workbook(path)

days_ws = book['Days']
for r in dataframe_to_rows(days_df, index=True, header=True):
    days_ws.append(r)

rates_ws = book['Daily Rates']
for r in dataframe_to_rows(rates_df, index=True, header=True):
    rates_ws.append(r)

settings_ws = book['Settings']
for r in dataframe_to_rows(settings_df, index=True, header=True):
    settings_ws.append(r)


with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    book.save(tmp.name)
    tmp.seek(0)
    stream = tmp.read()
```

What I would like to achieve is the ability to open an existing spreadsheet in write_only mode, to allow for data streaming into the workbooks without huge memory overhead. I know this is possible when creating worksheets, however I have not been able to find an example using an existing one.

I would be happy to work with any libraries or modules outside of OpenPyXl if anyone has other suggestions. Cheers!

Comment: You can combine `read-only` and `write-only`modes.

Comment: @CharlieClark thanks for your reply. I believe that is what is currently happening, and is the reason why my memory usage is so high. I am looking to reduce the memory consumption of the process. Currently it's ~600mb of memory to save a 2.3mb excel sheet.

Comment: No, it's not what you're currently doing.  `wb1 = load_workbook(path, read_only=True)` would be needed for that. `wb2 = Workbook(write_only=True)`

Comment: @CharlieClark if I understand correctly, that would open up my existing workbook in read only mode- preventing me from streaming data to it. While `wb2 = Workbook(write_only=True)` would create a completely separate new workbook which I could then write data into.

Comment: That's the way to do it to minimise memory use. You'll just need to stream the existing worksheets first before adding the data frames. Effectively you are always writing a new workbook anyway.

Comment: @CharlieClark Thanks for your comments yesterday, they've allowed me to get closer to where I want to be. Do you have any suggestions on how to transfer across the cell styles from the `read_only` workbook into the `write_only` wb?

Comment: Assuming you want per-cell styles, you are going to have to do this cell by cell. Named styles are probably the best way to do this to make sure you have the same style in different workbooks.

Comment: @CharlieClark I have tried doing this cell by cell, however the WriteOnlyCell always takes the position of A1, so I end up constantly overwriting my data. You wouldn't happen to have a code snippet or reference?

Comment: Need to see some code. This would be better on the mailing list.

Comment: @CharlieClark Happy to move to the mailing list; where would I find that?

Comment: It's listed in the openpyxl docs.

Comment: Where can I find this thread in the mailing list? I'm encountering the same issue.