# OpenPyXL and Large xlsx files

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Does anyone know how to use openpyxl with very large excel files (at least 16 MB)? I am hoping to automate a daily excel file I pull daily for my job. I am having a lot of issues because this file is so large. So far I have set the file to read_only=True just to open it, but I cannot write into it to change the values. Is anyone an expert on OpenPyXL and can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to modify an Excel file if you set the parameter `read_only` to `True`. If you cannot directly modify your existing Excel file because of excesive memory consumption, a possible approach could be opening such file as you are already doing with `read_only=True`, and create a new Excel file using `write_only=True`. Then, copy the existing worksheets from the first Excel to the new one, modify the values you want in the second and try to save the changes.

Other uses have already discussed a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53478863/open-an-existing-spreadsheet-in-write-only-mode).